# Using hostname to find Nodename or label to connect to Node

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have hostname that is found in a xml file but would need to use that hostname to get the node name in Jenkins to be able to connect to that node and do the scripting.

The hostname is example.co.uk and would like to use script to find the hostname in jenkins and get the node name of the Jenkins and use that as find-hostname. Is this possible?

```
//// 


      
    stage('use_nodename_found') {
    
    
        node("$find-hostname") {
            unstash 'db-process'
    sh """
        sudo su - postgres -c  'echo -e "-------------------------------System Information of current node running --------------------"'
    
    
    
    """.stripIndent()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following script to retrieve the Node name passing the Host. If you want to get the labels instead of `node.getNodeName()` call `node.getLabelString()`. Read more [here](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/slaves/DumbSlave.html).

```
def getNodeName(def host) {
    for(def node : Jenkins.instance.getNodes()) {
      if(node.getLauncher().getHost() == host){
        return node.getNodeName() 
      }
    }
    return null
}
```

Note: This is a basic script, make sure you d proper error handling.

**Update: Print all Hosts**

```
def getNodeName(def host) {
    for(def node : Jenkins.instance.getNodes()) {
        println node.getNodeName() 
        println node.getLauncher().getHost()
    }
    return null
}
```

Following is a full scripted Pipeline.

```
node {
    stage('Test') {
        echo getNodeName("172.17.0.3")
    }
}

def getNodeName(def host) {
    for(def node : Jenkins.instance.getNodes()) {
      if(node.getLauncher().getHost() == host){
        return node.getNodeName() 
      }
    }
    return null
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ycr..  I used this  code below but is returning blank. def getNodeName(def host) {
    for(def node : Jenkins.instance.getNodes()) {
      if(node.getLauncher().getHost() == example.co.uk){
        return node.getNodeName() 
      }
    }
    return null
}

Comment: @user5820327 Remove the `if` condition and try printing all the Host names. Check the updated answer.

Comment: It is returning blank

Comment: Do you have any Agents configured?

Comment: Yes, do you mean the slave agent. This is on premise server.

Comment: Yes do you have Slaves configured?

Comment: I have slaves configured

Comment: Then I'm not sure, the above script seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Do you run only this script or you put node agent before it as well?

Comment: I ran this in the Script console, but this should run within a Pipeline as well as long as you Approve the Script execution.

Comment: this is the whole script. #!/usr/bin/env groovy



    def getNodeName(def host) {
    for(def node : Jenkins.instance.getNodes()) {
        println node.getNodeName() 
        println node.getLauncher().getHost()
    }
    return null
}

Comment: @user5820327 I added a complete scripted Pipeline.

Comment: Thank you. It is working. I have to approve some getnodename and laucher